# Google Maps Api Error, Request Denied. Just for one time

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem about Maps Api. When I turned on/off an api from console, it works perfect but when I refresh the page, I get error about IP. It take me just see the result just for one time. Why I get this error? Any solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to say from the screenshots, but the error message indicates there could be a problem with the configuration for the API Key.  I would head to https://console.developers.google.com, go to the **Credentials** tab make sure the appropriate restrictions are in place for the API key you are using.

There is documentation how to troubleshoot which may be helpful @ https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#api-key-error